# How do I migrate from Python virtualdev environment to a Apache mod-python environment?

Tags: hosting, python

How do I migrate from Python virtualdev environment to a Apache mod-python environment?  I couldn't find a link anywhere on the internet that describes this.   My config.py file is in the root of my virtualdev directory.   I want to move it over to apache but I am unsure if I will be able to just copy it over or if its more complicated than that?   Does it take additional software configuration (aside from db connection)?

Comment: Maybe it's settings.py?

Comment: Im actually curious about how I would deploy Plurk-Solace .  I have it working in a dev environment now.  Is it just like an HTML page where you just copy the project files over into the APache root?

Answer (score 1):

When you say "virtualdev environment" I presume that you mean `django-admin.py runserver`.

[mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) is now greatly favoured over mod_python for serving through Apache.

You shouldn't need much modification to your project at all. Just simply create a script file. There are some details about how in the docs - [IntegrationWithDjango](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango)

Comment: There is no config.py file in Django so not sure that is what he meant. Can't think of any framework off hand that uses config.py.